# Sublimetext2 work with python console

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

I try to write two or more lines of code in python console in SublimeText2 editor and I get the following error when I press enter after ":"

```
    >>> for i in dir():
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in dir():
                 ^
   SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Is this a bug or did I do something wrong? And another question is any way to use multiline methods in console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sublime Text console is not meant to be used for coding.  It is there mostly for troubleshooting and plugin output.  Though you input multiple lines by using ;, I highly recommend against this.  Will Bond does this to install [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation), which if you have't downloaded already, I recommend you do.  If you're looking for a python REPL, check out Wuub's excellent plugin [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), which will give you a terminal/console like experience for quick python input.

Comment: another word i can't do any manipulation with text in editor through console by default? like for example through [NPP](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) python plugin console.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Notepad++ plugin but if you're planning on manipulating text, you'll probably have to make a plugin: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html  Could you give me an example of what you'd like to do?

Comment: it's not so difficult tasks, for example i have some text and i need to get some result from it with regexp, concatenate some data with this result and write it to editor, or in another case store it to MySQL base, actualy i agree that the best way to do this is create plugin, but realy sometimes it so easy to do this through console, for me maybe